# Monitoring s3 presigned URL usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Our service is using [S3 presigned URLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to allow our clients to download data.

Since S3 presigned downloads do not pass through our software stack at the time of download: We cannot be sure if the links were actually used by our clients.

We would like to understand how many bytes are actually being downloaded by our clients. (We give the clients the links, but we do not have visibility on what the actual traffic is)

We are looking for a simple way to monitor the usage (cloudwatch metrics, or any other AWS service). To get a single number: Total number of bytes downloaded by all our clients combined per specific date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [S3 usage report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/aws-usage-report.html). It should allow you to get the usage of the bucket. If your bucket is only used by your clients, this should be enough.

However, if the same bucket has other objects, you may want more granularity. In that case, the article above provides yet another link for enabling [server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html). This logs detailed records for each request, including the number of bytes sent.